# How to call web service using AzureSdk-iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, azure-mobile-services

Hi I am new to AzureSdk-iOS, My backend server is Windows Azure. I need to call web services. I don't know how to call it, I googled it but I did not get any answer. This is killing my time, Please help me.

Example Webservice: http://strandd-dev.azure-mobile.net/api/roadzensecurity/login?phone=9492266928&password=qwerty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Azure Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/), you can follow this tutorial: [How to call a custom API from an iOS client (JavaScript backend)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-call-custom-api/)

Answer (score 0):

User AFNetworking for call Web API , 
Here is the link for AFNetworking

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: your response is in xml formate, when you get you xml parse xml using NSXmlParser

Comment: did you get any success response @suthar

Comment: Use post method for hit your webapi

Comment: I tried with post, but getting error. I think this is not a general JSON or XML webservice @suthar

Comment: what response you are getting ?

Comment: { URL: http://strandd-dev.azure-mobile.net/api/roadzensecurity/login } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 41;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 07 Jul 2015 10:28:13 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"Service\"";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} })